# Parse: retrieving the last object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im trying to retrieving last object of a select order by desc field "createdAt":
In SQL something like this:

```
SELECT *   
FROM Message
ORDER BY createdAt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I try this, but does not work. The result is the first object:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Message")

query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.limit = 1

var lastMessage = "..."

if let objects = query.findObjects() as [AnyObject]?
{
    for object in objects
    {
        //Execute one time only and don't return the row that i want
        lastMessage = object["Text"] as! String
    }
}
```

With this lazy code, i get what i want, but i have to loop by all objects:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Message")

var lastMessage = "..."

if let objects = query.findObjects() as [AnyObject]?
{
    for object in objects
    {
        //Execute many times and return the row that i want int the last
        lastMessage = object["Text"] as! Strin
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastMessage = "..."        

let query = PFQuery(className: "Message", predicate: predicate)

query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

if let object = query.getFirstObject() as PFObject?
{
    lastMessage = object["Text"] as! String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using synchronous calls such as `findObjects()` at all costs. Instead, try using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Message")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.limit = 1
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
        if let firstObject = objects?.first {
            lastMessage = firstObject["Text"] as! String
        }
    } else {        
        // Log details of the failure
        println("query error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")
    }
}
```

Comment: but if you need the data synchronously ?

Comment: You need to perform all queries in the background so that they do not occur on the *main* thread. Among other things, the main thread controls the app's UI and if you *block* the main thread by performing a long-running synchronous operation, such as a query, the UI will be unresponsive until the query completes. If need to update the UI with data from Parse, you can handle all of that in the completion block. If you have some other logic that requires synchronous operations, use `NSNotifications` to structure the flow